# R packages keep asking for update

Tags: r, software-updates

The following R packages keep asking for updates, each and everyday, even after I update everything!

```
r-cran-kernsmooth
r-cran-mgcv
r-cran-nnet
r-cran-spatial
```

[image: update screen 1]

Here they are on the list of OS Updates (Aug/31). I clicked on Restart & Install, and saw no error messages at all.

[image: update screen 2]

Here they are again on the list of OS Updates (Sep/01). The version numbers are exactly the same.

That's annoying! What's wrong and how to solve it?

EDIT

I'm using Debian 9. These packages came (or should) from the following `sources.list` line:

```
deb http://cran.fiocruz.br/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/
```

Following @Bart suggestion, I tried to update a single package:

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade r-cran-spatial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libqt5concurrent5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  r-cran-spatial
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 130 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://cran.fiocruz.br/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/ r-cran-spatial 7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0 [130 kB]
Fetched 130 kB in 0s (262 kB/s)    
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 282913 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r-cran-spatial_7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0) over (7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0) ...
Setting up r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0) ...
```

I don't know, but is this line

```
Unpacking r-cran-spatial (7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0) over (7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0) ...
```

telling me that they're changing six for half-a-dozen? Anyway, I'll have to wait for the next OS Updates prompt to see if anything changed.

EDIT 2

Following @StephenKitt question:

```
$ apt policy r-cran-spatial
r-cran-spatial:
  Installed: 7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0
  Candidate: 7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0
  Version table:
 *** 7.3-11-2~stretchcran.0 500
        500 http://cran.fiocruz.br/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.3-11-1 500
        500 http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: maybe they simply did not update? Try updating them from command line to see if there are any issues. Anything in logs? any more information apart from screenshots you can provide?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?  Are you pulling the R stuff from your distros repositories or a 3rd party?

Comment: @Bart Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: @ivanivan Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: judging by the internet replies to similar issue, there might be hash sum mismatch on the packages on update servers and should resolve on it's own. you might want to contact the mirror owner to check if they're having any issues with packages.

Comment: If the problem is a hash sum mismatch, I should have got an error message, shouldn't I? But I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: What does `apt policy r-cran-spatial` say?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you, I edited the question.

Comment: OK, so that means that you are indeed getting the package from the repository you thought you were getting it from, and that there aren’t multiple repositories providing the same version with different contents. So it looks like this is the scenario Bart describes. *Why* that would happen is another matter... (The hash shouldn’t change on the server.)

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, but I only tried another mirror. Has the problem gone away meanwhile?